# Mysterious pipe

Tags: water-damage, old-pipes

While opening up opposing bathroom wall, I found a pipe that was made of sheet metal and had ventilation holes. I looked in the crawlspace to see if that pipe connected to something under the house, It did not. As you can see the pictures, it most likely goes to the roof. There was a lot of moisture that look like it had built up over [image]time. Does anyone have any idea what this pipe is?

Comment: Maybe a vent for a gas burning fireplace or water heater? One that was perhaps removed, but the pipe left in place?

Comment: Why is a photo of a thermostat (or other display) included in this group?

Comment: @keshlam that's possibley the hole the pics were taken through?

Comment: Is that an outside wall?  Is there any water pipes near the holes in the duct or in the wall?

Comment: Certainly looks like an old-style gas vent pipe. If the associated appliance is gone, should be no problem to remove it.

Comment: The thermostat is attached to the wall that’s the wire that runs up in the photo.